# maven の依存 artifact を読み込んだ状態で groovysh を起動するには？

Tags: maven, groovy

今、 maven の java プロジェクトがあって、そのプロジェクトで利用しているライブラリを REPL 的にテストして挙動をみたいと考えています。そのために、groovy を利用することを考えています。

pom ファイルがあるので、この情報を利用して、ローカルレポジトリの依存アーティファクトのクラスパスを読み込んだ形で groovysh を起動するのが理想なのですが、これを行う方法はありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

若干アナログな方法ですが

```
% mvn dependency:build-classpath
```

で classpath が取得できるので、これを用いて

```
% groovysh -cp <classpath>
```

とかどうですか。

Answer (score 0):

gmavenというプラグインを利用するのはどうでしょうか？
http://gmaven.codehaus.org/Executing+Groovy+Code

Comment: プラグインの利用方法やできることを簡単に含めてもらえると分かりやすくなると思います。ぱっと見、リンク先のドキュメントではmvnのターゲットとしてgroovyを実行する例の他には、対話的に実行する例がなさそうでした。

Comment: リンク先は認証が必要で、あくせすできませんでした。

Comment: codehausはサービス終了したので、現在はGitHub上に移っています。 https://github.com/groovy/gmaven